# How to display the name of the last user who modified my Custom Domain Object in Petrel RPT?

Tags: ocean, petrel

What do I need to do so that the RPT window display the name of the last user who modified my custom domain object (and the date)?

On my `DomainObject`, I've implemented a `LastModified` property of type `LastModifiedInfo` but it doesn't seem to be enough.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

If you implement IHistoryInfo it will show the last record of the history in the RPT dialog.